# JSONEncoder strips trailing zeros

Tags: ios, swift, jsonencoder

Is there a way to configure `JSONEncoder` to add trailing decimal mark and zero when converting `Double` (whole number) to JSON?

Code below illustrates the issue.

```
import Foundation

struct NumberTest: Codable {
    let number: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number
    }
}

let doubleNumber = NumberTest(number: 1.0)
let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(doubleNumber)

print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!) // {"number":1}
```

Desired result would be `{"number":1.0}`.

Comment: Why do you care? `1.0` and `1` are the same number.

Comment: Backend has validation that requires numbers to include fraction part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no (numeric) way.

JSON is just a platform independent *lightweight data-interchange format* and has only a single number format. `1` can be treated as `Int` or as `Double / Float`.

On the receiver side it can be formatted to any arbitrary format after deserialization.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, thank you for the answer.